# how to embed the php image path in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
var arrow2 ="<?php echo base_url() ?>/assets/images/apply_coupon/arrow-2.png" ;
var arrow1 ="<?php echo base_url() ?>/assets/images/apply_coupon/arrow-1.png" ;
img_array= new Array($arrow2,$arrow1);
```

I have created one `img_array`, and I have passed the php variable into it is it the correct format or not?

Comment: var arrow2 and arrow1 both are JS variable. Why did u make it as php variable? Change it to => img_array= new Array( arrow2, arrow1);

Answer (score 0):

change variable names used for making new array

`var img_array= new Array(arrow2, arrow1);

or

var img_array= [arrow2, arrow1];

`

or replace the var arrow1 to $arrow1 if you want to use dollar($) sign